# Именование жителей городов

Tags: существительные, словообразование, этнонимы

Человек, живущий в городе, может быть назван специальным существительным, которое обозначает его принадлежность к этому городу.

Например житель:

- Москвы — москвич,
- Омска — омич,
- Ленинграда — ленинградец,
- города Химки — химчанин, но не химец или химич,
- Уфы — уфимец, но не уфич или уфец.

Существует ли правило образования этих существительны на основе названия города?

Comment: Статья в Википедии не сойдёт? [«Этнохоро́ним».][e-ch] [e-ch]: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC

Comment: Обычно главное правило - чтобы не было ненужных ассоциаций. К примеру, если взять "химич" то это звучит как человек, который химичит. А "химец" звучит как "химический хлебец". Аналогично, "уфец" звучит как кто-то, кто часто говорит "Уф!".

Answer (score 5):

В большинстве случаев образование этнохоронима обусловлено не правилами, а местным обычием или "сложилось исторически". Во многих случаях сами жители города называют себя и своих земляков по-разному, например в городах, чьи названия менялись со временем, жители именуют себя более привычным образом.
Ещё сложнее с городами, чьё название длинно или необычно, как, например Екатеринбург (ранее - Свердловск) или Яя (посёлок в Кемеровской области).

Чаще всего, ответить однозначно на вопрос об используемом этнохорониме помогает только опрос местных жителей.